# how to pass request to parent class

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I write a plugin in Wordpress which is supposed to handle all rest API requests. In every request, `$token` should be parsed and I have to check in my DB, it's right or not. My question is I want to handle authentication in the parent class, I mean I have 2 classes. one `authentication` and the other is `handler` which extends from its parent `authentication`.for example, if the request is `/get/pictures/`, I have to check in `authentication` class if the token is set then handle its request, otherwise return false.
how can I parse `$request` to the parent class first

```
  add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
        register_rest_route('myapi/v1', '/get/pictures/', array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array(new Handler(), 'get_pictures')
        ));
    });

  // in Authentication.php
    class Authentication {
       public function check_token_valid(){
         //check if token exist in the `$request`
       }
   }

 //in handler.php
  class Handler extends Authentication {
    public function get_pictures($request){
        // do some stuff
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
            register_rest_route('myapi/v1', '/get/pictures/', 
               array(
                   'method' => 'GET',
                   'callback' => array(new Handler(), 'get_pictures'),
                 'permission_callback' => function() {
                    return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
                    }, 
            ));
        });




 //in handler.php
  class Handler extends Authentication {
    public function get_pictures($request){
        // do some stuff
    }
 }
```

Comment: when the child is initiated, in the child's constructor, validation must be done.

Comment: Now check it will call the parent function in children constructor

Comment: check_token_valid method needs `$request`, how can I parse it through the child's class?

Comment: the `$request` will be passed to the `get_pictures` method

Comment: why need to create two class it is not required to achieve your requirement.There is permission_callback function available in wp reset api

Answer (score 0):

```
// in Authentication.php
    class Authentication {
       public function check_token_valid( $request ){
         //check if token exist in the `$request`

       }
   }

 //in handler.php
  class Handler extends Authentication {
    public function get_pictures($request){
        // Validate it

        if( $this->check_token_valid( $request ) == false ) {
        {
            return false;
        }

        // perform actions

    }
 }
```

This link might help you :

> https://wpshout.com/custom-register_rest_route-wordpress/